REGEXP replace with blank
I am exploring a database using BigQuery and following a relatively old document which is returning an error with the below query. Entries in the column in question has the form
|column1|
|:---   |
|tag1,3125;tag2,024|
Where the numbers after the comma are irrelevant character offsets. The code is trying to 1) delimit rows by the semicolon and 2) remove the comma and character offset and just retain the tag name. The suggested expression is the below but it returns the error: "Syntax error: Unclosed string literal at [3:52]"
SELECT person, COUNT(*) as count
FROM (
select REGEXP_REPLACE(SPLIT(column1,';'), r',.*', ") person
from 'db_name')
group by person
ORDER BY 2 DESC

I have tried several other iterations but all return an error. Any suggestions on how to amend the query?

What is the link to the document you reference?  Is your code a copy/paste in this StackOverflow question?  Could you have entered " (double quote) as opposed to '' (two single quotes) ....

Yes basically a copy and paste. Agree that looks like the cause but i tried two single and it still didn't fix it. If I replace the double quotes with single I get a different error: No matching signature for function REGEXP_REPLACE for argument types: ARRAY, STRING, STRING This is the document: https://blog.gdeltproject.org/google-bigquery-gkg-2-0-sample-queries/

HI @celeste could you please share any demo dataset ?

Changing to single quotes "seems" to be the right answer and the double quotes was the ORIGINAL problem.   I'd suggest switching to two single quotes ... and NOW we have a NEW puzzle (but the correct one to solve).  As @Sourav was suggesting, we now need to see the schema and data ... specifically of the column called "column1".

After split, column1 becomes an array as the error suggest. How do you want to handle this array? Do you want to replace each item in the array?

Fixing the error reported
I am not sure that SPLIT with REGEX_REPLACE is the way to go. When I corrected the double quote to 2x double quotes, I got an error related to the SPLIT being an array, but you're then trying to work with that as a string.
with db_name AS (
  SELECT 
      "|column1| |:--- | |tag1,3125;tag2,024|" AS column1
)

select REGEXP_REPLACE(SPLIT(column1,';'), r',.*',"") person
  from db_name

Error:
No matching signature for function REGEXP_REPLACE for argument types: ARRAY<STRING>, STRING, STRING. Supported signatures: REGEXP_REPLACE(STRING, STRING, STRING); REGEXP_REPLACE(BYTES, BYTES, BYTES) at [6:8]
So even if you overcome the error described, you will still not be able to use REPLACE.
Dealing with the business problem, not the technical problem
It seems like you are looking to extract the values from the "tag" values up to (but not including) the comma, then you can extract them as follows.

Clean the data we don't need from the start and end, i.e. anything
before the first "tag" value, and the pipe delimiters.
Split the data at the semicolon so we only work with the "tag..." strings. It is treated as an array, so we need to turn it back into a string.
Find the comma in each row and strip that and everything after it.
Group by the person values.

The following code is broken up so I can explain it along the way. You can consolidate it as required, but it won't be so readable.
--specify the supplied string example in a CTE
WITH
  tmp AS (
    SELECT 
      "|column1| |:--- | |tag1,3125;tag2,024|" AS person
  ),

Next we strip out the spurious data up to the first "tag" value and remove any remaining pipe characters (|).
This changes |column1| |:--- | |tag1,3125;tag2,024| to tag1,3125;tag2,024| and then to tag1,3125;tag2,024, as follows:
  tmp2 AS (
    SELECT 
      REPLACE(SUBSTRING(person,STRPOS(person,"tag"),LENGTH(person)),"|","") AS person
    FROM tmp
  ),

Now we split the value at the semicolon from rows to create an array of tag... values.
  tmp3 AS (
    SELECT 
      SPLIT(person,";") AS person
    FROM tmp2
  ),

This gives us the array of
tag1,3125
tag2,024

Next, UNNEST makes the array into rows of strings so we can manipulate them further.
Find the index position of the comma and take the start of the string up to that index position, but we have to go back 1 character.
e.g.

STRPOS("tag123,xyz", ",") returns 7 as the comma is in index position 7.
STRPOS("tag123,xyz", ",")-1 returns 6
SUBSTRING("tag123,xyz",1,STRPOS("tag123,xyz", ",") returns index positions 1-7, i.e. tag123,
SUBSTRING("tag123,xyz",1,STRPOS("tag123,xyz", ",")-1) returns index positions 1-6, i.e. tag123

  tmp4 AS (
    SELECT 
      SUBSTRING(u,1,STRPOS(u,",")-1) AS person
    FROM tmp3,
      UNNEST(person) AS u
  )

This gives us the string values of
tag1
tag2

Finally you can group by the person values:
SELECT person, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM tmp4
GROUP by 1
ORDER by 2 DESC


Super helpful, it got me most of the way there. The earlier part removing piping wasn't necessary for my use case (that was a formatting issue in how I posed the question). The only part that didn't work was the SUBSTRING. I got an error: Third argument in SUBSTR() cannot be negative. The work around was just including the comma as it still served the purpose, but just visually was less compelling.

Excellent, glad to have been able to help you.
